# UITextView disappears from ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I have the strangest thing happening.  My Text Views and Image Views randomly become invisible on my View Controller.

I am developing using Xcode 6 on OSX 10.9
I have a View Controller that is wrapped in navigation controller.
In the middle of the View Controller I have Text View.  When I add an Image View or move controls somehow the Text View disappears.  It doesn't re-appear at run time.  There doesn't seem to be overlap as far as I can find.  On the left hand side the navigation shows that the text view is there and I can select it and edit properties.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: are you sure your not covering your view with another view?

Comment: not sure how that would be.  I only have a label, a text view and a button....

Comment: are you using the textview and image view programmatically

Comment: @Gagan - I am not.  I am just trying to use the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend upgrading to Xcode 6, and using its new [view debugging](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html) feature to locate your view. The issue could be with incorrect Auto Layout constraints, or some views overlapping one another, etc.

Comment: Sorry, misspoke I was using 6 (correcting the question now).  I haven't tried the view debugging, but I will now.